# Spark parse nested json with variable json keys

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jsonparser

I have below structure

root

```
 |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- programs: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- **{ program id }**: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Some_Flags: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- abc: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- def: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ghi: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- xyz: boolean (nullable = true)




“groups” : [
 {
  … some other fields …
  “programs” : {
     “123c12b123456c1d76a4f265f10f20a0” : {
        “name” : “test_program_1”, 
        “some_flags” : {
           “abc” : true, 
           “def” : true, 
           “ghi” : false, 
           “xyz” : true
        }, 
        “date” : ISODate(“2019–11–16T03:29:00.000+0000”)
     }
 }
]
```

> val data = spark.read.json("path").map(customParser)
> How do I use custom parser to map to case class?

data is coming from mongo db.
Need to distributed parse so that I can iterate over each line.

Comment: Could you please add a few lines of the input json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the json document has a variable key (the `program id` is not a constant key but varies for each entry) Spark cannot infer the schema. One option is to process the document manually:

The case classes:

```scala
case class SomeFlags(abc: Boolean, def1: Boolean, ghi: Boolean, xyz: Boolean)
case class Program(var programId: String, date: String, name: String, someFlags: SomeFlags)
case class Group(programs: Array[Program])
case class Groups(groups: Array[Group])
```

The [companion objects](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/companion-objects.html) for extracting the data fields from the json string:

```scala
object Groups {
  def unapply(values: Map[String, Object]) = try {
    val groups = values("groups").asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Object]]]
    val grps = new ListBuffer[Group]()
    for (group <- groups) {
      val Group(grp) = group
      grps += grp
    }
    Some(Groups(Array(grps: _*)))
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(ex) => {
      println(ex)
      None
    }
  }
}
  
object Group {
  def unapply(values: Map[String, Object]) = try {
    val programs = values("programs").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]]
    val prgs = new ListBuffer[Program]()
    for ((k, v) <- programs) {
      val Program(prg) = v.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]];
      prg.programId = k;
      prgs += prg;
    }
    Some(Group(Array(prgs: _*)))
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(ex) => {
      println(ex)
      None
    }
  }
}

object Program {
  def unapply(values: Map[String, Object]) = try {
    val SomeFlags(flags) = values("some_flags").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]]
    Some(Program("pid", values("date").asInstanceOf[String], values("name").asInstanceOf[String], flags))
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(ex) => {
      println(ex)
      None
    }
  }
}

object SomeFlags {
  def unapply(values: Map[String, Object]) = try {
    Some(SomeFlags(values("abc").asInstanceOf[Boolean], values("def").asInstanceOf[Boolean], values("ghi").asInstanceOf[Boolean], values("xyz").asInstanceOf[Boolean]))
  } catch {
    case NonFatal(ex) => {
      println(ex)
      None
    }
  }
}
```

The critical part here is inside of `Group.unapply` where the `prg.programId` is manually set to the key of the map containing all the programs.

Finally the Spark code. [DataframeReader.textFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#textFile(path:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BString%5D) is used to read the file (each line should contain a whole Json document). The result is a `Dataset[String]` and any other datasouce that produces a dataframe containg one complete Json document per line will work too.

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.{DefaultScalaModule, ScalaObjectMapper}

val ds: Dataset[String] = spark.read.textFile(<path to file>)

val ds2: Dataset[Groups] = ds.map(s => {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper //https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034844/2129801
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  val obj = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Object]](s)
  val Groups(groups) = obj
  groups
})
```

`ds2` now has the schema:

```
root
 |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- programs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- programId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- someFlags: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- abc: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- def1: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ghi: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- xyz: boolean (nullable = false)
```

Things to improve:

- better error handling within the `unapply` methods
- replace the `map` function with `mapPartitions` to improve the performance